# Why do I get 'divide by zero` errors when I try to run my script with Rakudo?

Tags: raku, rakudo

I just built Rakudo and Parrot so that I could play with it and get started on learning Perl 6.  I downloaded the Perl 6 book and happily typed in the first demo program (the tennis tournament example).

When I try to run the program, I get an error:

```
Divide by zero
current instr.: '' pc -1 ((unknown file):-1)
```

I have my `perl6` binary in the build directory.  I added a scripts directory under the rakudo build directory:

```
  rakudo
  |- perl6
  \- scripts
     |- perlbook_02.01
     \- scores
```

If I try to run even a simple hello world script from my scripts directory I get the same error:

```
#!/home/daotoad/rakudo/perl6

use v6;
say "Hello nurse!";
```

However if I run it from the `rakudo` directory it works.

It sounds like there are some environment variables I need to set, but I am at a lost as to what the are and what values to give them.

Any thoughts?

**Update:**

I'd rather not install rakudo at this point, I'd rather just run things from the build directory.  This will allow me to keep my changes to my system minimal as I try out different Perl6 builds (Rakudo * is out very soon).

The README file encouraged me to think that this was possible:

> ```
>    $ cd rakudo
>    $ perl Configure.pl --gen-parrot
>    $ make
> ```
>
> This will create a "perl6" or "perl6.exe" executable in the
>   current (rakudo) directory.  Programs can then be run from
>   the build directory using a command like:
>
> ```
>    $ ./perl6 hello.pl
> ```

Upon rereading, I found a reference to the fact that it is necessary to install rakudo before running scripts outside the build directory:

> Once built, Rakudo's `make install` target will install Rakudo
>   and its libraries into the Parrot installation that was used to
>   create it.  Until this step is performed, the "perl6" executable
>   created by `make` above can only be reliably run from the root of
>   Rakudo's build directory.  After `make install` is performed,
>   the installed executable can be run from any directory (as long as
>   the Parrot installation that was used to create it remains intact).

So it looks like I need to install rakudo to play with Perl 6.

The next question is, where rakudo be installed? README says into the Parrot install used to build.

I used the `--gen-parrot` option in my build, which looks like it installs into `rakudo/parrot-install`.  So rakudo will be installed into my `rakudo\parrot-install`?

Reading the Makefile, supports this conclusion.  I ran `make install`, and it did install into `parrot_install`.

This part of the build/install process is unclear for a newbie to Perl6.  I'll see if I can up with a documentation patch to clarify things.

Off the top of my head:

1. Emphasize running `make install` before running scripts outside of build.  This requirement is currently burried in the middle of a paragraph and can be easily missed by someone skimming the docs (me).
2. Explicitly state that with `--gen-parrot` will install perl6 into the `parrot_install` directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you run `make install` in Rakudo?

It's necessary to do it to be able to use Rakudo outside its build directory (and that's why both the README and http://rakudo.org/how-to-get-rakudo tell you to do it.

Don't worry, the default install location is local (in parrot_install/bin/perl inside your rakudo directory).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I updated my question to give a bigger response.

Answer (score 3):

In response to your update I've now updated the README:

http://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/261eb2ae08fee75a0a0e3935ef64c516e8bc2b98

I hope you find that clearer than before. If you still see room for improvement, please consider submitting a patch to rakudobug@perl.org.

Comment: Can I accept both your answers? Thank you, all your work is really appreciated. You and the rest of the perl6 team are doing amazing work in the face of a vicious environment of FUD and naysayers. My sincerest thanks to you all.